# Changes made to variables in a method not changing in the main method JAVA

Tags: java, methods

i'll start by saying im quite new to Java, ive got reasonable experience in python but Java is fairly new to me.

My problem is that I have created a method to make sure 4 random numbers are all unique to one another, ive done this by just comparing every possible combination using while loops.

I can see that my code works

```
public static void EqualValues(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    while(num1 == num2 || num1 == num3 || num1 == num4) {
        num1 = ran.nextInt(9);
        num1 += 1;
    }
    while(num2 == num1 || num2 == num3 || num2 == num4) {
        num2 = ran.nextInt(9);
        num2 += 1;
    }

    while(num3 == num1 || num3 == num2 || num3 == num4) {
        num3 = ran.nextInt(9);
        num3 += 1;
    }
    while (num4 == num1 || num4 == num2 || num4 == num3) {
        num4 = ran.nextInt(9);
        num4 += 1;
    }

    System.out.println(num1);
    System.out.println(num2);
    System.out.println(num3);
    System.out.println(num4);
    System.out.println(".........");
}
```

Which will output 4 unique numbers ie:
2
6
8
4

However, when I do the same in my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random ran = new Random();

    int num1 = ran.nextInt(9);
    int num2 = ran.nextInt(9);
    int num3 = ran.nextInt(9);
    int num4 = ran.nextInt(9);

    num1 += 1;
    num2 += 1;
    num3 += 1;
    num4 += 1;

    EqualValues(num1, num2, num3, num4);

    System.out.println(num1);
    System.out.println(num2);
    System.out.println(num3);
    System.out.println(num4);
}
```

I get what seems to be the four original numbers before they were checked ie:
2
6
4
4

If someone could point out where i have gone wrong. I hope i have described my question so its easy to understand.

Comment: you just change the values of the local variables in that method.

Comment: It's because your method is receiving "copies" of your variables, therefore the originals are not modified

Comment: See [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Ok i see, could you explain how exactly I go about fixing that please?

Comment: either you return those values to the main method, or you declare the variables on class level, and don't pass them as parameters to the method

Answer (score 0):

What happens is the following: when you pass your variables to `EqualValues` (which you should rename to `equalValues` to follow convention) it actually receives "copies" of them, which it cannot modify. There are two ways to work around that:

1 - You return the modified values, possibly in an array.

2 - You don't pass any parameters, and instead declare your variables as static and let the method access them directly.

However, I'd propose another approach altogether: pass a `Set` object to your method. That way, the method will modify only the **contents** of your `Set`, and it would also handle repetitions for you (since `Set`s only allow unique values) so that your code would be much cleaner.

Example:

```
private static final Random RNG = new Random();

private static void fillWithRandoms(Set<Integer> set) {
    while(set.size() < 4) {
        int rando = RNG.nextInt(9) + 1;
        set.add(rando);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    fillWithRandoms(set);

    System.out.println(set);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! This is very helpful thought maybe a touch confusing right now. I'll have a look at using sets, i've never come accross them but if each valuue is totally unique as you say, they would be ideal. Cheers

Comment: If you have further questions, make sure to look for them here. If no one's asked it yet you're free to ask them yourself. Also, I'd recommend you take a look at Oracle's Java tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html. It's very thorough, and also has a section on the Collections API (which includes the `Set` interface).